# How to predict a specific text or group of text using nltk Text Analysis libraries after necessary preprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, classification, logistic-regression

All code is in python. I have a python list named "**corpus**" that contains reviews in total 2000(+ve and -ve reviews both). The main/important part of mycode is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=2000, max_df=0.6, min_df=3, stop_words=stopwords.words("english"))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer  
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X = transformer.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logistic_reg = LogisticRegression()
logistic_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now I want to predict a sentence as +ve or -ve('1' or '0'). The sentence is

```
sample = ["you are a nice person and have a good life"]
```

How should I go about predicting for the above.(I know what is the role of CountVectorizer and TdfidfTransformer but it is sort of confusing me with the TdfidfVectorizer)

Comment: But you are not using `TdfidfVectorizer` anywhere in your code? What do you want exactly. `TdfidfVectorizer` is just a combination of `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you have achieved by `CountVectorizer`  and `TfidfTranformer`  can be achieved by `TfidfVecorizer` alone.

Answer to your question:

```
sample = ["you are a nice person and have a good life"]
```

This is your sample data you want to predict.Here i have used transform method on vectorizer (CountVectorizer)

```
Count_sample = vectorizer.transform(sample)
```

After transforming CountVectorizer we have to use transform method on transformer(TfidfTranformer)

```
Tfidf_sample = transformer.transform(Count_sample)
```

After completing all the transformation of data use predict function of `LogisticRegression`

```
predicted = logistic_reg.predict(Tfidf_sample)
```

Comment: tfidf vectorizer is same as after passing the corpus through countVectorizer and tfidfTransformer. Its working fine now.